# Strange PHP empty() error

Tags: php

I don't want to show all the code but I am validating all the data with php and everything is working as it always does, until this variable just keeps giving me the same weird response:

```
$ABN = $_POST['ABN'];
```

I am grabbing the variable with a POST method, and checking it with

```
if(empty($ABN)) {
     $msg .= '<br> ABN Needed';
     $proceed = false;
 }
```

So, before you say that obviously the POST is not giving me any data, I used:

```
var_dump($ABN);
```

And it is giving me the same input I put in on the form, so obviously this is not empty?

```
string(11) "-the-value-i-am-passing-in"
```

I have checked through all my code and made sure that $ABN is not being set null anywhere else and even moved the code so the sequence in my code is now one after another but this issue is still occurring. Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

```
    $ABN = $_POST['ABN'];
    var_dump($ABN);

    if(empty($ABN)) {
        $msg .= '<br> ABN Needed';
        $proceed = false;
    }
```

Comment: Which error are we talking about?

Comment: Ende, empty is saying his var is empty when it isn't

Comment: I think i have read something about the empty() function not always being correct. Try isset() and see what that gives you

Comment: *"-the-value-i-am-passing-in"* - Is that literally the value, or a contrived example of a different value?  What the value *is* is important to `empty()`.

Comment: @Andreas is right thank you so much , Guys probably best not to use empty();

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `empty()` as long as you know what values that function considers to be empty. They are [documented in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Comment: Use like this  if(isset($ABN) && empty($ABN)) { $msg .= '<br> ABN Needed'; $procced = false; }

Comment: @David The value is an  Integers sorry i am not giving the value because it is bound to the ABN(Australian Business Number) Registry

Comment: I'd guess problem is actually that you misspelled varaible $procced in provided code and it is being checked as if ($proceed)

Comment: @NoOorZ24 that was just a typo while writing it up nothing to worry about

Comment: @KaiMc: Well, since the details of the problem are "trade secrets" then all we've really been able to do is guess.  It's great that you found something that *appears to be* working.  But as a general word of advice you'll want to look into the documentation of the functions you're using and test/validate your logic rather than just making guesses and hoping for the best.  In the future, including *actual details* about the problem will help.  (I assure you, the Australian Business Registry does not have an international copyright on *integers*.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `isset()` on the actual post var, and `is_null()` further on.

```
$ABN = isset($_POST['ABN']) ? $_POST['ABN'] : null;

if(is_null($ABN)) {
    $msg .= '<br> ABN Needed';
    $proceed = false;
}
```

Comment: why `is_null` if `empty()` checks for all ?

Comment: `empty()` acts quirky at times

Comment: In which case ?

Comment: https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: In his case. Or he wouldn't have asked? It's in the docs what works and what wont

Comment: @BunkerBoy delboy is right i changed it to isset() and it worked straight away

Comment: If form is correct your ['ABN'] will always be set. empty() checks for unfilled field, isset() for element missing in form

Comment: @KaiMc are you using checkbox or input field?

Comment: @KaiMc glad I could help! Check the link Andreas left! Can you mark this as the answer please? :-)

Comment: @delboy1978uk done, Thanks again everyone

Comment: @Kai Mc in your case empty() will only failed, if `$_POST['ABN'] == '0'`

Comment: @BunkerBoy i see where you are coming from but not in my case because as i posted $ABN is outputting a string(11)  Type as shown in the var_dump(),

Comment: @NoOorZ24 - A clarification: `isset()` returns true a variable is defined and not null. `empty()` returns true if a variable is not defined, null and if the variable contains a value which it considers to be empty (like `0`, `0.0`, empty string, `false` and more). Neither functions are specifically for forms/fields.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author)*.

I changed `if(empty()){}` to `if(!isset()){}`. Thank you David for the solution.